# installing a package in R by copying code?

Tags: r, installation, package

I must run R code on a virtual machine that does not have an internet connection and only has an old version of R installed (R 2.10.1).  I want to install the package LiblineaR, which was first created for a version of R that is more recent than 2.10.1. For this reason, I can't install it by just secure copying the tar.gz file over to the virtual machine, because the tar.gz file only works for newer versions of R.

When I simply try to copy the code for the "LiblineaR" function, it also doesn't work because when I call that function, it gives me the message:

```
Error in .C("trainLinear", as.double(W), as.double(if (sparse) data@ra else t(data)),  : 
C symbol name "trainLinear" not in load table
```

Does anyone know how I can work around this (or what the error message means?)

Let me know if I can provide any extra information.

Comment: Why do you have `a virtual machine with no internet connection`?

Comment: You have the build chain tool installed, and you compiled the package correctly?

Comment: Do you expect to get specific advice when you don't even mention the OS?

Comment: I see no dependencies for that package. Why cannot you build that copied  `tar.gz`?

Comment: The virtual machine is running Linux and my current computer is running Mac OSx 10.8.4. I cannot built the tar.gz because this is a newer package that was only built after R 2.10.1 was made, and I get an error message along the lines of "This package requires R >=2.15.2."

Comment: Can you install the latest version of R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually a very simple fix, I was copying the function definition along with the line `<environment: namespace:data.table>` at the end. Once I didn't copy that line, it worked. My apologies for creating a ruckus about nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to borrow Raymond Chen's patented Psychic Debugging Powers and say that it's not possible; the package you want to install has dependencies on builtin R functions that don't exist in R 2.10.1 but do exist in R 2.15.2 (hence the requirement).

The line

```
C symbol name "trainLinear" not in load table
```

strongly suggests a dependency on a native C function.

Answer (score 0):

The „trainLinear“ function you can find in the src folder for the package . To source the provided  C/C++ code should not be the problem, but the next problem you will face is that the package depends on other packages as well (eg. See R code in package library("SparseM")
) and the whole thing starts again.

If you solved all that problems it´s still like Eric said, you can get a problem with build in functions of the tow R versions.

I think it is easier to work on the internet problem :)

HTH